# Grandchild from sibling A emits, parent updates the value, but sibling B is not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

This is the parent template with 2 children

```
<payment :isEditing="isEditing" @action="onActionButtonClick" />
<create-details v-if="isCompanyDetailsCreating" @action="onActionButtonClick" />
```

Inside the child **create-details** I have a grandchild that emits **onActionButtonClick**, it's received by the parent and the parent it changes the value of `isEditing`.

My problem is that this value change in `isEditing`, I'm not receiving inside **payment** component. This is what I have tried inside PaymentComponent, but it's not working

```
props: {
  isEditing: { type: Boolean as PropType<boolean>, default: false },
},
emits: ['action'],
setup(props, { emit }) {
  const isEditingButton = ref(props.isEditing)

watch(props.isEditing, (first, second) => {
 isEditing.value = props.isEditing
})
```

The error I'm receiving in the watch warning is this one. Would be great if someone could help me. I know I could achieve it with store, but I would appreciate help.

> Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly WatchSource[]'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean is a type that can be used directly, you only need to to use `PropType` for more complex types and when using TypeScript.

So try to define the prop like this:

```
props: {
  isEditing: { type: Boolean, default: false },
},
```

EDIT:
And you can't update a prop, or what is your intention with this line in the watch:
`isEditing.value = props.isEditing`
Is this a ref you omited in the code?

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props

Comment: Changing it I keep with the same problem, It's not working the update from parent to child

Comment: True, it's working removing isEditingButton and just using isEditing. Thank you Thomas